# Suggested Edit Reviewing Concerns

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Since I've unlocked the suggested edits queue I would say that it is probably my favourite queue to work through and I often look back at edits I've reviewed to see how people agreed with me and so that I learn to review more consistently and more appropriately with how edits should be done, which is why when I saw this edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16886272

I was surprised to see that a user with almost 10k rep, approved the edit! <sub>(fortunately another user rejected it)</sub>

The edit in question simply changes the following piece of code

```
<?php echo the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $author_id ); ?>
```

into:

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $author_id ); ?>
```

By itself, this would be alright, however to circumvent the edit minimum the user added the following at the bottom of the post:

> (Edited incorrect echo of function that prints data)

Which is extra noise and a blatant abuse of the ability to make edits.  This is the second time today that I've seen a similar action, the first time being on this edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16884762

Where the editor made it possible to see the `<div>` tag *again* to circumvent the minimum length, they added: `<!--comment because edition requires al least 6 chars -->` to the beginning of the post. This slipped through reviewers not looking at the markdown and it was accepted!

It's concerning to see that users are attempting to/succeeding in approving these edits, especially as a user which tries hard to stop these edits getting through.

What can we do about this as it certainly seems to be a recurring problem? A possibility would be to implement more intense suggested edit audits, as while they are intended to prevent robo-reviewing, they should be stopping this kind of review?

Comment: *"it is probably my favourite queue to work through"* Well, that won't last. And you've already begun to discover why. :-)

Comment: Well, if you see a crazily wrong review of a question (not talking about the first example; that might be a misclick), like one adding a spam link into a post and that got approved (even by just one person), then you can also flag that post, use a custom flag and then explain the issue clearly so a moderator can handle that (for example providing a review to that person).

Comment: @Tom my concern is not what *I* can do about these, I could just rollback or improve bad edits, but what can be done to prevent this from happening in the first place

Comment: *"but what can be done to prevent this from happening in the first place"* - not much. Everyone can approve bad suggestions or decline got ones as long as they aren't banned from review :/.

Comment: @Tom Yes, and I suppose a *"flag reviewer"* button would be out of the question due to abuse

Comment: That doesn't prevent bad reviews and is essentially the same as I said in the first comment with the custom flag :P.

Comment: @Tom There have been lots of proposals on how to improve review (many bad, but some not).  SO hasn't done anything with it in years though.  They've made the decision that it's not worth making further improvements to them, even knowing that there are major problems with them.

Comment: @Servy Well, that's nothing new (sadly). One of the worst cases is the unfixed Triage review and it's "Needs editing" button :/.

Comment: @NickA You can at least be glad that these days bad reviewers are *just* a sizable minority (to the extend that you see bad reviews like this many times a day, but it's not like you don't ever see edits reviewed correctly).  In the past the overwhelming majority of reviewers were bad reviewers, and approximately 100% of suggested edits were approved, regardless of whether they were appropriate or not.  It was a hard fought fight to get as far as we've gotten.

Comment: @Tom Indeed, I've long since considered that one of the most egregious things to still be unfixed. If SO cared, in the slightest, they'd have at least fixed things like that, that would cost them almost nothing, so I simply don't hold out hope for time spent attempting to fix *difficult* problems.